# Tile python game (pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game-engine

Making a tile game in python using the library pygame. In the game, the timer through the function should work from the top left. Everything is displayed for me, but for some reason the account is not kept. You need to consider that I need a variable with seconds, because I'm going to increase the number of enemies with increasing seconds.
Here is the code:

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
import random

#         R    G    B
WHITE = (255, 255, 255,)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
DARKGREY = (40, 40, 40)
LIGHTGREY = (43, 43, 43)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 200, 0)

WIDTH = 1008  # 16 * 64 или 32 * 32 или 64 * 16
HEIGHT = 768  # 16 * 48 или 32 * 24 или 64 * 12
FPS = 60
TITLE = "TITLE GAME"
BGCOLOR = DARKGREY

TILESIZE = 48
GRIDWIDTH = WIDTH / TILESIZE
GRIDHEIGHT = HEIGHT / TILESIZE


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, dx=0, dy=0):
        if not self.colide_with_walls(dx, dy):
            self.x += dx
            self.y += dy

    def colide_with_walls(self, dx=0, dy=0):
        for wall in self.game.walls:
            if wall.x == self.x + dx and wall.y == self.y + dy:
                return True
        return False

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x = self.x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = self.y * TILESIZE


class Wall(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.walls
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE


class MobY(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(6, 9)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + TILESIZE:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(6, 9)


class MobX(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0  # random.randrange(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(6, 9)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedy
        if self.rect.left > WIDTH + TILESIZE:
            self.rect.x = 0  # random.randrange(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(6, 9)


class MobYY(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE)
        self.rect.y = GRIDHEIGHT * TILESIZE
        self.speedy = random.randrange(6, 9)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE)
            self.rect.y = GRIDHEIGHT * TILESIZE
            self.speedy = random.randrange(6, 9)


class MobXX(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = GRIDWIDTH * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(6, 9)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x -= self.speedy
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.rect.x = GRIDWIDTH * TILESIZE
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(6, 9)


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        pg.key.set_repeat(1, 15)

    def new(self):
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.mobs = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self, 10, 10)
        for i in range(1):
            m = MobY()
            self.all_sprites.add(m)
            self.mobs.add(m)
        for i in range(1):
            m = MobX()
            self.all_sprites.add(m)
            self.mobs.add(m)
        for i in range(1):
            m = MobYY()
            self.all_sprites.add(m)
            self.mobs.add(m)
        for i in range(1):
            m = MobXX()
            self.all_sprites.add(m)
            self.mobs.add(m)
        for x in range(-1, 22):
            Wall(self, x, -1)
        for x in range(-1, 22):
            Wall(self, x, 16)
        for x in range(-1, 17):
            Wall(self, -1, x)
        for x in range(-1, 17):
            Wall(self, 21, x)

    def run(self):
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def time(self):
        self.font = pg.font.Font(None, 50)
        self.font_color = pg.Color('springgreen')
        self.frame_count = 0
        self.total_seconds = self.frame_count // FPS
        self.seconds = self.total_seconds % 60
        self.output_string = "TIME: {0}".format(self.seconds)
        self.text = self.font.render(self.output_string, True, self.font_color)
        self.screen.blit(self.text, [10, 10])
        self.frame_count += 1
        if self.seconds >= 10:
            self.playing = False

    def draw_grid(self):
        for x in range(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (x, 0), (x, HEIGHT))
        for y in range(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (0, y), (WIDTH, y))

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        self.draw_grid()
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        self.time()
        pg.display.flip()

    def events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.quit()
                if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                    self.player.move(dx=-1)
                if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    self.player.move(dx=1)
                if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                    self.player.move(dy=-1)
                if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                    self.player.move(dy=1)

g = Game()
while True:
    g.new()
    g.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `time` method inside of `Game` class which is called in your `main_loop` you are setting `self.frame_count = 0` every cycle, so it changes between 0 and 1 constantly. You need to remove `self.frame_count = 0` and to put it into the `__init__` method, so it would not reset every frame.

Comment: This is a very stupid mistake on my part. Thank you!